# Trouble with document join query in MongoDB

Tags: mongodb

I am trying to join the following two documents based on the related fields, namely `users._id` and `addressschemas.userId`.

example `users` document;

```
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("58f74901b3ec8e2d0bc898d5"),
    "fullName" : "public user",
    "firstName" : "public",
    "lastName" : "user",
    "email" : "user@gmail.com",
    "password" : "$2a$10$thYCJS62ejUxxzIlpIfiXeRxswQPzU4sVhc4PeoGxAXN3/IBxnxeO",
    "mobile" : "9876543210",
    "countryCode" : "+91",
    "accountEnabled" : true,
    "__v" : 0
}
```

example `addressschemas` document;

```
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("58f9b18880a35c281078f42b"),
    "userId" :  ObjectId("58f74901b3ec8e2d0bc898d5"),
    "deliveryName" : "test",
    "deliveryAddress" : "new address",
    "deliveryState" : "Haryana",
    "deliveryCity" : "Gurgaon",
    "deliveryZipCode" : "122001",
    "deliveryCountryCode" : "+91",
    "deliveryMobile" : "9876543211",
    "deliveryEmail" : "subadmin2@email.com",
    "__v" : 0
}
```

The desired result from before-mentioned join should be the following;

```
{

    "_id" : ObjectId("58f74901b3ec8e2d0bc898d5"),
    "fullName" : "public user",
    "firstName" : "public",
    "lastName" : "user",
    "email" : "user@gmail.com",
    "password" : "$2a$10$thYCJS62ejUxxzIlpIfiXeRxswQPzU4sVhc4PeoGxAXN3/IBxnxeO",
    "mobile" : "9876543210",
    "countryCode" : "+91",
    "accountEnabled" : true,

    "userId" :ObjectId("58f74901b3ec8e2d0bc898d5"),
    "deliveryName" : "test",
    "deliveryAddress" : "new address",
    "deliveryState" : "Haryana",
    "deliveryCity" : "Gurgaon",
    "deliveryZipCode" : "122001",
    "deliveryCountryCode" : "+91",
    "deliveryMobile" : "9876543211",
    "deliveryEmail" : "subadmin2@email.com"
}
```

And the query that I am using to achieve this;

```
db.getCollection('users').aggregate([
  {
    $match: {
      _id: ObjectId("58f74901b3ec8e2d0bc898d5")
    }
  },
  {
    $lookup: {
      from: "addressschemas",
      localField: "_id",
      foreignField: "usersId",
      as: "results"
    }
  },
  {
    $project: {
      addressschemas: {
        $filter: {
          input: "$_id",
          cond: {
            $eq: ['$$addressschemas.userId', '$users._id']
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
])
```

But the result of the above query is empty, can anyone tell me the problem with it?

Comment: You are not storing the Object ID of users collection `usersId` as an `ObjectId` object, but as a String, that might be the trouble IMO. Can you try to use a `$let` logic to map `ObjectId` to String before lookup?

Comment: But there is no way to map `ObjectId` to String during aggregate pipeline, so you might need to do it reverse from `addressschemas` document. Or easy way is to modify your type of `userId` in `addressschemas` document to `ObjectId`

Comment: I am new in mongoDB,I have updated the schema of address for userId, So can you suggest me how to do this. And what will be correct query ?

Comment: So `usersId` was `ObjectId` type already? How about the `$match` in your query, it also tries to match `_id` with a String. If you have a trouble with aggregate pipeline, just remove the last operation from it, and check part by part, so first try with only `$match` operation in it, and check it returns correctly, and debug bit by bit in case of trouble

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can get an approximate result with the following query;

```
db.getCollection('users').aggregate([
  {
    $match: {
      _id: ObjectId("58f74901b3ec8e2d0bc898d5")
    }
  },
  {
    $lookup: {
      from: "addressschemas",
      localField: "_id",
      foreignField: "userId",
      as: "address"
    }
  },
  {
    $unwind : "$address" 
  },
  {
    $project: {
      __v: 0,
      "address.__v": 0,
      "address._id": 0,
      "address.userId": 0
    }
  }
])
```

Which will result in the following document, using your test data;

```
{
  "_id": ObjectId("58f74901b3ec8e2d0bc898d5")
  "fullName": "public user",
  "firstName": "public",
  "lastName": "user",
  "email": "user@gmail.com",
  "password": "$2a$10$thYCJS62ejUxxzIlpIfiXeRxswQPzU4sVhc4PeoGxAXN3/IBxnxeO",
  "mobile": "9876543210",
  "countryCode": "+91",
  "accountEnabled": true,
  "address": {
    "deliveryName": "test",
    "deliveryAddress": "new address",
    "deliveryState": "Haryana",
    "deliveryCity": "Gurgaon",
    "deliveryZipCode": "122001",
    "deliveryCountryCode": "+91",
    "deliveryMobile": "9876543211",
    "deliveryEmail": "subadmin2@email.com"
  }
}
```

Since `$lookup` creates a new field together with the original fields of `users` document, you'd have the values of `addressschemas` in an array under this new `address` field, therefore I am using an `$undwind` operation to get rid of this array. There is no easy way to move them up one level, to the root, as it is in your desired result and I think it is better to represent the address data like this.

Obviously I am assuming the user document contains a singular address only, if that is not the case, the `$unwind` operation will result a multiple of the above objects with each containing a different `addess` field, but from your desired result, I deduced that you have one-to-one relationship between these two documents.

Comment: Thanks@but when I am running above query then I am getting null ( No records ).

Comment: @ShubhamVerma with the data you've given I was able to get the above result, were your example documents correct?

Comment: @ShubhamVerma I've just tested with your example documents on [online mongo shell](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/tutorial/insert-documents/), it returned the result in my answer. Maybe the `$match` part in the query is the trouble, since you wish to do this for all documents, drop the `$match` operation from the aggregate pipeline, and try again, you should get an array of documents that are given in my answer.

Comment: still not getting the result. I am trying to do this

Comment: @ShubhamVerma that is interesting, I think it should've worked, the query works for your example documents on your question, so should've worked on your other documents also. Can you confirm that the documents in your question are valid?

Comment: @ShubhamVerma another possibility is that, if there is no connection between your tables, i.e. no user has an address linked, than that also would return an empty result, are you sure that there is at least a single address document that is linked to a user document?

Comment: I have created a new scenario , and then tried  , then it working.., Thank you.

Comment: @ShubhamVerma I am glad! But what was the problem?

Comment: The problem was , I was using userId: { type: 'string', format: 'nonEmptyOrBlank', required: true },  and now i am using userId: { type: mongoose.Schema.Types.ObjectId, format: 'nonEmptyOrBlank', required: true } in my schema.   Then its worked. You were right it was $match{ }.  :)

Comment: But tell me one things , If there were more than two collections to get the data from ,  then what changes will i do ?

Comment: @ShubhamVerma you mean the `$lookup` with multiple tables? You can do two `$lookup`'s targeting different fields, that would work I think. You can ask a separate question for that.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/142803/discussion-between-shubham-verma-and-bureaquete).

Answer (score 2):

MongoDB defines relationship in two ways

(1) References
(2) Embedded documents

References are preferable in application where many to many relationship exists among entities.

Embedded documents are preferable in application where one to many relationship exists among entities.

In above mentioned scenario it seems that one to many relationship exists between user and addressschemas.

Hence addresses of respective user can be defined as an embedded document within user document thereby facilitating retrieval of user document in single trip to database server.

E.g

```
{
    "_id": ObjectId("58f74901b3ec8e2d0bc898d5"),
    "fullName": "public user",
    "firstName": "public",
    "lastName": "user",
    "email": "user@gmail.com",
    "password": "$2a$10$thYCJS62ejUxxzIlpIfiXeRxswQPzU4sVhc4PeoGxAXN3/IBxnxeO",
    "mobile": "9876543210",
    "countryCode": "+91",
    "accountEnabled": true,
    "__v": 0,
    "addressschemas": [
        {
            "deliveryName": "test",
            "deliveryAddress": "new address",
            "deliveryState": "Haryana",
            "deliveryCity": "Gurgaon",
            "deliveryZipCode": "122001",
            "deliveryCountryCode": "+91",
            "deliveryMobile": "9876543211",
            "deliveryEmail": "subadmin2@email.com"
        }
    ]
}
```